Allow overflow during spring animation in SwiftUI
How do I allow the content of the list to overflow during the spring animation?

As you can see, the borders of the texts gets cut off during the animation.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var big = false
    @Namespace private var firstNamespace
    @Namespace private var secondNamespace
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                withAnimation(.spring(response: 2, dampingFraction: 0.2)) {
                    big.toggle()
                }

            } label: {
                Text("Resize")
            }
            List{
                ZStack {
                    if (big) {
                        VStack {
                            Text("first")
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 200)
                                .border(.red)
                                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "first", in: firstNamespace)
                            Text("second")
                                .frame(maxWidth: 500, maxHeight: 200)
                                .border(.red)
                                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "second", in: secondNamespace)
                        }
                    } else {
                        HStack {
                            Text("first")
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 200)
                                .border(.red)
                                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "first", in: firstNamespace)
                            Text("second")
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 200)
                                .border(.red)
                                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "second", in: secondNamespace)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                .padding(8)
            }
        }
    }
}


I need it to be a List because I want to show list items below this, while keeping the entire screen scrollable. I cannot use a ScrollView since a List is invisible inside of it.


Can you use .listStyle(.grouped)? If not, you'd need to write your own List.

Try removing the content margins.
When you do this, a row separator becomes visible. You can hide it if you don't want it to be there.
Also, you may want to put a Section around the list content, then add padding to the section, to compensate for the removed margins.
List {
    Section { //  added
        ZStack {
            // ...
        }
        .listRowSeparator(.hidden) //  added
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
        .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
        .padding(8)
    }
    .padding() //  added
}
.contentMargins(0, for: .scrollContent) //  added


BTW, there is no need to use two different namespaces for the .matchGeometryEffect, one single namespace could be used for both cases (because the matched geometry ids are different).

EDIT The changes above prevent the clipping from happening, but as you remarked in the comments, it is just like applying .listStyle(.grouped) to the List. This means, if you have other rows in the same section, or other sections in the list, then these have no margins at the side.
If the swappable views will only be shown at the top of the List, but other rows that follow should have content margins in the regular way, then another approach would be to show the switchable views in the header of a Section. This solves the clipping problem, while keeping the content margins for other rows, but of course it only works if the swappable content can be moved to the section header.
List {
    Section {
        Text("row2")
        Text("row3")
    } header: {
        ZStack {
            // ...
        }
    }
}



This looks great! But how do I make it so that a "ordinary" section of list items below it appears with the default style and not pushed against the edges of the screen?

That's what I thought too, but I cannot get it to work. The padding doesn't seem to work.

Unless I'm missing something, the latest update reintroduces the original problem where the borders gets cut off during the animation. Do you have amodifier on the List still, or no?

@OskarPersson Sorry, you're right. The last examples I posted did not have the content margins removed (because the modifier was in the wrong place). So the list rows looked fine, but the animation was being clipped again. I'm now seeing what you are probably seeing, where rows in the same section, or in a following section, have no margins. Haven't found a solution yet, invalid row examples removed again from answer.

@OskarPersson answer updated with another possible workaround (put the swappable content in a section header, if possible)

Building on the answer by @Benzy Neez which addresses the cut off borders, here's how you could deal with the styling of other sections, so they are not pushed against the edges of the screen, and without having to put the animated content in a section's header:
import SwiftUI

struct OverflowSpringAnimation: View {
    @State var big = false
    @Namespace private var firstNamespace
    @Namespace private var secondNamespace
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button {
                    withAnimation(.spring(response: 2, dampingFraction: 0.2)) {
                        big.toggle()
                    }
                    
                } label: {
                    Text("Resize")
                        .foregroundStyle(.blue)
                }
            }
            
            List{
                Section {
                    ZStack {
                        if (big) {
                            VStack {
                                Text("first")
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 200)
                                    .border(.red)
                                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "first", in: firstNamespace)
                                Text("second")
                                    .frame(maxWidth: 500, maxHeight: 200)
                                    .border(.red)
                                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "second", in: secondNamespace)
                            }

                        } else {
                            HStack {
                                Text("first")
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 200)
                                    .border(.red)
                                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "first", in: firstNamespace)
                                Text("second")
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 200)
                                    .border(.red)
                                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "second", in: secondNamespace)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                    .padding(8)
                }
                
                Section("Ordinary section") {
                    VStack(spacing: 10) {
                        Text("Row 1")
                        Text("Row 2")
                        Text("Row 3")
                    }
                }
                .customSectionBackground()
                
                Section("Another section") {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                        ForEach(4..<7) { index in
                            Text("Item \(index)")
                            if index != 6 { //optional check to hide divider for the last item, comment out condition to show for all
                                Divider()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .customSectionBackground(.cyan.opacity(0.1))
            }
            .contentMargins(0, for: .scrollContent)
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    public func customSectionBackground(_ color: Color = .white) -> some View {
        self
            .listRowBackground(
                Color.clear
                    .background(color, in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
                    .padding(.horizontal, 20)
            )
            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
    }
}

#Preview {
    OverflowSpringAnimation()
}


